# Postgres dynamic sql and list result

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, record

I used EXECUTE(for dynamic sql) and SETOF(result is returning as list), but it is the wrong :(

```
create table test as
select 1 id, 'safd' data1,'sagd' data2
union
select 2 id, 'hdfg' data1,'sdsf' data2;

create or replace function test2(a varchar) returns SETOF record as
$BODY$
declare x record;
begin
for x in execute a loop
RETURN NEXT x;
end loop;
return;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

select * from test2('select * from test');
```

Comment: ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: select * from test2('select * from test');
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to know in advance the structure of the returned record

```
select * from test2('select * from test') s(a int, b text, c text);
 a |  b   |  c   
---+------+------
 1 | safd | sagd
 2 | hdfg | sdsf
```

Or if the returned set will always be a set of the test table then use the Akash's proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
create or replace function test2(a varchar) returns SETOF RECORD as
```

with

```
create or replace function test2(a varchar) returns SETOF test as
                                                          ^^^^ name of table (it specifies the datatypes of the set)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some OUT params.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test2(a character varying, OUT id integer, OUT data1 text, OUT data2 text) RETURNS SETOF record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE a;
end;
$$;
```